# What is the correct way to implement a xml file as a data source for a connection string in a VS project?

Tags: c#, xml, datasource

My project use a XML file, called `informat.xml`, which contains all the info necesary to connect to a database. I use it in a connection string on my `App.config`, like so

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <!-- things -->
    <connectionStrings>
       <add name="ServerAS400" connectionString="Data Source=.\informat.xml" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

This works on my computer, but when called remotely (to a folder that is a copy of my Debug folder), it gives me an error saying the XML file could not be loaded. The file itself is on the Debug folder of my project, and it's added as a resource in the resource tab on the project properties.

Edit: further testing made me realize that using the absolute path for `informat.xml` do make it work. So the problem would be the `.\` part, probably.

The code that trigger the error is the following one

```
        using (Sql400Connection connection = new Sql400Connection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ServerAS400"].ConnectionString))
            try
            {
                connection.Open(); // ERROR HERE

                // some code

                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
```

So, what is the proper way to add the file to the project, or to be called in the `App.config`?

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but what is a `Sql400Connection`? Where is it defined? Who creates/publishes that class?

Comment: Equivalent to the `SqlConnection` class. The company I'm making this for is using AS400 servers, and I'm using a dll that provides equivalent class for connecting to it.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was curious because I had never seen a Connection class take an Xml file as its config source before and was wondering of the internals of that would be the source of the error.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for "informat.xml". You place all your connection details like below in the connection string itself.
Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a requirement. Also it has 33 parameters so kinda annoying to have it on a single line.

Comment: Read XML path like this AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase+"\\informat.xml"